# Is it possible to get a reference to the logger Spring is using?

Tags: java, spring, logging

According to be Spring Framework documentation, logging is the only mandatory dependency of Spring. It uses Apache Commons Logging by default, or can be configured to use SLF4J or Log4J instead. My question is for the application I am writing using Spring, instead of using a differnt logger class and instantiating a new logger object in my application, is it possible to get a reference to the logger Spring is using for itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure - loggers are only referenced by name.  So if Spring uses "org.springframework.beans.abc" (for example) as a logger name, you can also ask for a logger of the same name.  (Spring doesn't log using just one logger / name - it uses several, depending upon what you're using in Spring - as it should.)

However, I would strongly recommend against doing this.  The cost of instantiating a new logger object should be minimal - and any savings in doing this would be more than offset by the additional confusion of doing so.  Spring logs to Spring logger names.  Your code should log to a logger name unique to your code.  Otherwise, if something is logged, how do you know if it is coming from Spring code or your code?  This would completely defeat the purpose of logger / category names.

Answer (score 2):

Need to clear up a few things. Apache Commons Logging is a logging facade, not a logger itself. The Spring libraries use this facade to avoid coupling to any specific logging implementation.

Spring (or anything else that use Apache Commons Logging) can be configured to use SLF4J by providing a bridge implementation that SLF4J provides for Apache Commons Logging. SLF4J is also a logging facade but has improvements over Apache Commons Logging and is what I would personally recommend use for logging in your code. Logging with SLF4J also avoids coupling to any specific logging implementation.

You can find more information about SLF4J at their website http://www.slf4j.org. The first page of the [SLF4J Manual](http://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) demonstrates how to create a logger and use it. When your code uses an SLF4J logger it will delegate logging at runtime to a real logger like Log4J, java.util.logging or Logback depending on which slf4j binding you provide on the classpath.

Generally for logging, a common practice is that you have a logger for each different class that logs (by naming each logger with the fully qualified classname of the class using it). This principle is demonstrated in the SLF4J manual I linked above.